# Everyday countdown using Javascript

Tags: javascript, countdown

I would like to create a simple **Daily** CountDown using JavaScript. The countdown should work similarly to this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

But instead of counting down to the fixed value of var CountDownDate, I would like the countdown to re-start every day at 3 PM.

Could anyone suggest appropriate amendments to the code above to achieve desired functionality or feel free to write a new code.

Many thanks for any input!

EDIT: Just to address your questions and elaborate further - I simply need a countdown that notifies my customers that they have only so much time left to order today IF they want the same-day-shipping. In other words, if you want your products to be dispatched TODAY you have 1hr:2min:3sec left. When the timer reaches 0 (at 3 PM) I want it to re-start to the 24hour mark and obviously expire again at 3 pm the following day. I would love it to take into consideration user's unique timezone. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: what do you mean by restart can you explain more in detail ?

Comment: so if you start from exmaple 30 days , at 3 PM it must restart value to 30 days?  Or just update date once per day

Comment: 1) Should it tick "down" or up, or should it be dependent on `countDownDate`?

Comment: 2) What timezone are we talking about; just the user's own timezone?

Comment: added more information to the original post

Comment: I should mention that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` is "sometimes after X", not exactly on X milliseconds. So if the user have the same page open for an hour, your timer will be a few seconds too slow. Nothing to be bothered with IMHO, but just a heads up. The correct way is to use requestAnimationFrame, which updates every time the screen repaints.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Date equaling 3 PM today. If it's already past 3 PM today, add 24 hours, making it 3 PM tomorrow.

```
const now = new Date();
const countDownHour = 15;
let countDownDate = new Date(
   now.getFullYear(),
   now.getMonth(),
   now.getDate(),
   countDownHour
);
if (now.getHours() >= countDownHour) {
    countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: What happens if it's 4pm?

Comment: At 4 PM, it should show 23 hours remaining. Oops.  :D yeah no.

Comment: Yeah that happens when you post without thinking too much. Fixed.